# Is this response normal in Amazon MWS reports?

Tags: amazon-mws

[image: Reports response]

Hi. I am trying Amazon MWS for the first time. I have referred to - https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_Overview.html

I made a call as shown in the diagram on that page. I am using the scratchpad.

1. Called the Request Report with required fields. In this case ReportType -
   "_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_"
2. Then I called the GetReportRequestList with the "ReportRequestId"
   returned from the previous call.
3. Finally I am calling the - "GetReport" with the "GeneratedReportId"
   which I got from the call previous to this and I get the response as
   the above image.

I have no idea how to parse and use it. Can't make any sense about the format returned in the final call (Shown in the image).

If anyone worked with this API. Please point me to the right direction.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the ReportType, you'll either get a XML file or a CSV file back. The [ReportType enumeration page](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) in the docs will tell you which is which. While the [XML format](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf) is somewhat well documented here, the CSV files are not, but most should be self-explanatory. `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` returns such a CSV file. You may be confused by the fact that one of its fields contains some HTML.

Since you don't state which programming language you intend to use: You can open a CSV file in Excel (or LibreOffice). Please note that unlike most CSV files, these are separated by tabs, not by commas or semicolons. Also, to answer your initial question: yes, this is normal.